# Using relevant position in a vector to find index

Tags: r, indexing

I have a vector for each participant in a study that describes their eating periods. For example Participant 1 and 2 respectively have

```
> eating.period.1
 [1] "Day 1 (1/18/15)"     "    Breakfast"       "    Morning Snack"   "    Lunch"           "    Afternoon Snack"
 [6] "    Dinner"          "    Evening Snack"   "Day 2 (1/19/15)"     "    Breakfast"       "    Morning Snack"  
[11] "    Lunch"           "    Afternoon Snack" "    Dinner"          "    Evening Snack"   "Day 3 (1/20/15)"    
[16] "    Breakfast"       "    Morning Snack"   "    Lunch"           "    Afternoon Snack" "    Dinner"         
[21] "    Evening Snack"   "Average"   


> eating.period.2
 [1] "Day 1 (9/16/15)"     "    Breakfast"       "    Morning Snack"   "    Lunch"           "    Afternoon Snack"
 [6] "    Dinner"          "    Evening Snack"   "Day 2 (9/17/15)"     "    Breakfast"       "    Lunch"          
[11] "    Afternoon Snack" "    Dinner"          "    Evening Snack"   "Day 3 (9/21/15)"     "    Breakfast"      
[16] "    Lunch"           "    Dinner"          "    Evening Snack"   "Average"
```

How do I get the index for an eating period between Days X and X+1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use something like this:

```
find_index <- function(eating_period, day1, day2, meal){
  is <- grep(day1, eating_period, ignore.case = TRUE)
  ie <- grep(day2, eating_period, ignore.case = TRUE)
  im <- grep(meal, eating_period[(is+1):(ie-1)], ignore.case = TRUE)
  is+im
}
eating.period.2 <- c("Day 1 (9/16/15)",
"    Breakfast",
" Morning Snack",
"    Lunch",
"Afternoon Snack",
"Day 2 (9/17/15)")

find_index(eating.period.2, "day 1", "day 2", "breakfast")
```

**Output**:

```
 # 2
```

Comment: Each participant has their own dates so I am looking for a function that I can use across participants without knowing each of their dates.

Comment: @its.me.adam change the `day1` and `day2` arguments to your dates, this function can handle any dates

Comment: There are 100+ participants with their own dates. I do not want to look each of the dates up to use a function.

I could use `regmatches(eating.period.1, gregexpr("(?<=\\().*?(?=\\))", eating.period.1, perl=T))` to grab the date for Day 1 but I don't know how to adjust this for Day 2 and 3.

Comment: You can use `day1 = "Day 1"` and `day2 = "Day 2"`, the function will still work as intended

Comment: Indeed, my apologies. 

However it still won't work for my intention, as I need to grab the index for a specific eating period.The tricky part is that I want this function to work across participants, while the participants each have their own unique eating periods (i.e. some are missing Breakfast for Day 1 e.g.),

Sorry if I am confusing. It is hard to put this into words.

Comment: @its.me.adam Can you elaborate what you mean? Please include input and output to the function

Comment: I just made an edit to be more clear.

In the input, I would like to be able to write "Breakfast" between Day 1 and Day 2 e.g. 

The output would then give me the index for Breakfast that is located between these days.

Comment: Elegant! But how would you adjust it to ALSO work for cases where the days are not in order? E.g. Day 2 is before Day 1 in `eating.period`. (Edit: I suppose if statements in `find_index` would work but they would need to account for each possible order of Day 1 2 and 3.)

Comment: You just need to change the order of `is` and `ie`. Use an if test to determine which one is greater. That's it